# Wordpress conditional header content dependent on page and children

Tags: php, wordpress

On my Wordpress website, I want like to show different header content for page "254" and all it's descendants.

The code that I'm using is

```
if ( $post->post_parent == '256' ) {
  <p>My parent is 256 or I am 256</p>
}

else {
<p>My parent is not 256</p>
}
```

This code however doesn't work. I am new to PHP, so I'm unsure what other solutions could be explored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
if(is_page(256) || wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID()) == 256 ) {
   echo '<p>My parent is 256 or I am 256</p>';
} else {
   echo '<p>My parent is not 256</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get custom layouts for a page is to use a page-specific template in Wordpress.

Give the page template a custom name with the ID, `page-256.php` and put that page in the root of your project's theme. It will override your typical page header located in `page.php`.

It is very important to name that template JUST like that, with `page-ID#.php`. WordPress is setup to look for that naming convention and create the override. Check out the larger [WordPress template hierarchy](http://wphierarchy.com/) to learn more about how overrides work.

Answer (score -1):

Should be something like :

```
$parent = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID );
if ($parent == 256 || post->ID == 256) {
    #Do something
    echo "<p>My parent is 256 or I am 256</p>" ;
} else {
    #Do regular things.
    echo "<p>My parent is not 256</p>" ;
}
```

Look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id) for function reference.

Also note that I used "[echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)" to print html .

If you want to print HTML without 'echo' you can also close php with `?>`
and reopen it after thr HTML with: `<?php`